# nameerror unitialized constant rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on deploying a rails 5 api. After much trail error its almost functioning. The problem I am having is that I am running into a 500 server error. I sshed into the instance to check the logs and I keep getting this name error. The log output:

```
[2017-11-14T15:41:47.289647 #10484]  INFO -- : [6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 244ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
F, [2017-11-14T15:41:47.290161 #10484] FATAL -- : [6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc]
F, [2017-11-14T15:41:47.290225 #10484] FATAL -- : [6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc] NameError (uninitialized constant Net::HTTP):
F, [2017-11-14T15:41:47.290245 #10484] FATAL -- : [6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc]
F, [2017-11-14T15:41:47.290263 #10484] FATAL -- : [6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc] app/models/user.rb:41:in `authorization'
[6d21f1c2-6770-42a2-93be-cd68ee0441fc] app/models/user.rb:17:in `create_new_auth_token'
```

I thought I forgot to require net/http, but when I check the require statement was already there. I'm not understanding this at all. Further, I checked the console and its showing that the package has been included. The code:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

def authorization(client_id, token)
        encrypted_token = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(token)
        params = { "token": encrypted_token, "client": client_id }

        Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("path to api"), params)
  end
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on?

Comment: Are you able to run or test this method in rails console? Does it gives error there as well ?

Comment: Yes, it does work in console.

Comment: Try to restart application server. May be you editted the file after starting the server.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank You.